# IPBoard Error Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_STRING

Tags: php, html

I have been having this error with `IPBoard` when trying to install a skin/theme. I get this message when I apply it to my forum:

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_STRING in /home/a7952789/public_html/forum/cache/skin_cache/cacheid_7/skin_global.php on line 83
```

So I decided to check It out I re-parsed it and it said no errors in CODE. here is the exact line of code:

```
$this->functionData['globalTemplate'][$count_3b65c7bc63b10c5a7f84294eb9b75dd2]['array_header_items'] = $array header_items;
```

Answer (score 0):

`$array header_items` doesn't make any sense. It might be a typo for `$array_header_items`, although it's hard to guess what it is supposed to be.

Comment: ".$this->registry->getClass('output')->getTemplate('global')->include_lightbox(1) . "

Comment: @user2525868 Sorry but I am not your personal programmer. I already replied to your original question, and you don't provide any context or error message, there is no way I can help you more than I already did.